# Basic authentication Apache don't work

Tags: apache-httpd, password

I have a problem with Apache, I need protect the site folder with a password. I have done so many times but in this server it doesn't work and I do not what to do.

I insert this to `.htaccess` file:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Members Only"
AuthUserFile /opt/.htpasswd
require valid-user
```

I have create the file `/opt/.htpasswd` with `htpasswd` command but when I go to the site don't show any popup that ask the password.

Comment: Can the Apache process read `/opt/.htpasswd`? Can it read the associated `.htaccess` file? Does the Apache configuration [allow configuration override](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride)?

Comment: AllowOverride is set to All and i change owner to apache but nothing changed

Comment: No responses to requests for clarification. VTC

Answer (score 1):

Someone I respect once gave me this incredibly insightful advice on debugging `.htaccess` issues:

Before you try anything else, add the following line at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
CopaCabanaDrama True
```

Then attempt to load a page that should be controlled by that `.htaccess` file.

If you're not getting a HTTP 500 error, then your immediate problem is that Apache currently *isn't even reading the `htaccess` file*, and you should sort that out before you try anything else.

(If it does parse the `.htaccess` file, it'll read that line and throw out an error because that line is deliberately nonsense)

Check the main apache config (usually found under `/etc/apache2/` with the specific part of the config that directly addresses the directory you're dealing with likely being one of the files under `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/`.

Check those files until you find the one with a `DocumentRoot` matching part of your current directory's path, then look at its `AllowOverride` and `AccessFileName` settings for clues.

(If it's the latter you'll want to give your site admin a big ol' side-eye, but it's possible)

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have the `auth_basic` module installed or enabled in this Apache. You can check by doing `ls /etc/apache2/mods-enabled` to see if auth_basic.load is there and enable it by doing:

```
a2enmod auth_basic
```

As basic authentication (over non-encrypted HTTP) can pose a security problem, because the username and password can be sniffed, it is not always enabled by default.

Comment: i have apache 2.2.15 and module auth s enabled: "LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so"