# Using htaccess and htaccess file to configure a folder to be accessible via web only by specific user

Tags: linux, shell-script, centos, webserver, htaccess

I do apologize in advance for my dumb question because I am a beginner in Linux and CentOS.

How can I use an htaccess file and htpasswd file to configure the new folder to be accessible via the web only by entering the username for example (use1) and password (123) in my restricted area called "private" in `/var/www/Html`. I wrote this to make "private" directory: `sudo mkdir -p /var/www/html/private` then I wrote this: `sudo htpasswd /var/www/html/private/htaccess use1` and this: `echo (echo 123; echo 123) | htpasswd use1`.

When I run my bash it's not giving any errors but anyone can still access the "private" file. I don't know how and with what commands can I use the "htaccess" and "htpasswd" files configure the "private" folder to be accessible via the web only by entering username as "use1" and password as "123". Also is there any way I can do it with automating prompt (I mean I prefer when I am running the bash not asking for the password and read it automatically, in bash script, please?

Thank you kindly.

Comment: Related - [Basic authentication Apache don't work](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/172262/100397) and [How to set up authentication for the personal userdir in Apache?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/368900/100397)

Comment: @roaima thank you I will follow that, u guys r great